# ASP.NET MVC4 - Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed. [MySql and Entity Framework 5.0]

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, asp.net-4.0

I am using .NET 4.0 to develop a MVC4 application. My hope is to be able to use the database first approach with a MySQL Database using Entity Framework 5.0.0. I am using the following packages to accomplish this: Entity Framework 5, MySql.Data.Entity 6.7.6, MySql.Data 6.7.6. I have the MySql.NET Connector 6.7.6 installed as well. The issue I am running into occurs when trying to connect to the existing DB to build out the model.

Here are the relevant sections of my web config:

```
<section name="entityFramework" 
         type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, 
         version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" 
/>
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type ="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity">
    <parameters>
      <parameter value="MySql.Data.Entity" />
    </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
</entityFramework>
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" 
         invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" 
         description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" 
         type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.7.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

And here is the connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyContext" 
     providerName="System.Data.MySqlClient" 
     connectionString="Server=MyServer; 
                       Port=3306; 
                       Database=MyDbName; 
                       UID=mysqltest; 
                       Pwd=mysqltestpassword;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Steps taken:

1. I currently have the MySql.Data and MySql.Data.Entity references copying locally, so that has been ruled out.
2. I checked the machine.config file in both the 64 and 32 bit .NET framework for any missing out of place entries and found no errors.

I have spent about 15 hours on this very issue and am currently pulling my hair out. Please help! Also, I would like to avoid using the MySql for Visual Studio plugin.

Thanks in advance!